# react native call detection

Tags: react-native, android-phone-call

I tried to use react-native-call-detection but it does not get any of the event callbacks in Android 11. Any help would be appreciated! Alternatively is there another way to get call state detection in react native

Comment: call state detection as in?

Comment: as in offhook, Disconnected, dialing etc